# Does laser coherence length impact phase noise?

Tags: laser, noise, photonics

I am trying to simulate laser phase noise numerically by creating a random phase $\phi(t) = \sqrt{2\pi\Delta\nu_L} \int_{0}^{t} dW(t)$, where $\Delta\nu_L$ is the laser linewidth in Hz and $\int_{0}^{t} dW(t)$ is an Ito integral (or Brownian motion). This is then introduced into a pulsed function
\begin{equation}
x(t) = e^{-\frac{4\ln(2)}{\tau_p^2} t^2} e^{i\phi(t)},
\end{equation}
where $\tau_p$ is the FWHM of the Gaussian pulse envelope. Ideally, I should be able to see a noisy envelope field, which is affected by the random phase $\phi(t)$. However, I have found that the time-scales between the laser pulse width and the random phase variations have a pretty significant impact on how "noisy" the pulse is.

For instance, let us define the coherence time of the laser as $\tau_{coh} = (\pi\Delta\nu_L)^{-1}$. Then, if $\tau_{coh} < \tau_p$, we see a noisy envelope field $x(t)$, but when $\tau_{coh} \gg \tau_p$ we don't see much noise at all, as illustrated in the plots below:

[image]

The top plots are the Gaussian function (black) and $e^{i\phi(t)}$ (red) plotted separately, whereas the bottom plots are represent $x(t)$ (the product of the Gaussian with the noisy phase function).

This seems like a straight-forward observation, but I haven't been able to find anything in the literature that talks about this sort of effect. The reason why this is significant to me is because I am doing some simulations involving short pulses (nanoseconds long), and the laser linewidths I have found quoted in some experimental setups are in the kHz range, which would effectively have a negligible phase noise contribution to the overall signal.

Does anyone know of any papers/literature that talks about this that I can cite?